# unserialize() return empty

Tags: hooks

I have a variable that holds a serialized string that I want to convert back into a PHP Array.

```
$str = 'a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:2:"id";s:24:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";s:11:"description";s:3:"Two";s:9:"users-idt";s:36:"x6543rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrd";}}';
$arr = unserialize($str) // returns an empty;
```

But when I take the same string an run unserialize() on it outside Drupal, it works perfectly. Could this be a drupal issue?,

Using Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Cant see how it could be drupal, how are you determining that its returning empty? Are you doing a

```
var_dump($arr); die;
```

directly after your code?